How was Kuratowski's problem for closure and complementation proven
Kuratowski's problem states that, if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and $c,k,i:\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(X)$ are the complementation, closure and interior operator relative to $X$. It is then a theorem that:

The monoid $\langle c,k\rangle$ is of order at most 14.
The monoid $\langle k,i\rangle$ is of order at most 7.

How was this proven? Could anyone give a sketch? I couldn't find any modern resource on this.
On Wikipedia, there is an example of a subset of $\mathbb R$, from which exactly 13 other sets can be generated this way, but no explanation of why more than 14 is impossible in $\mathbb R$ or any topological space. I find it amazing that this is implied to be true for even topological spaces of higher cardinalities, with topologies also of higher cardinalities. A general monoid, generated by two elements, one of which is its own inverse (c) and the other idempotent (k), could easily be infinite, so these constraints are clearly not enough to prove the theorem.

Wikipedia has a proof that no more than 14 sets can be constructed. You can write every set as an alternating string of closures and complements (interiors reduce to that). The three reduction rules and induction allow you to reduce to the 14 possible sets listed.

The Wikipedia article has a link at the end to a proof in "The Kuratowski Closure-Complement Theorem" by Gardner and Jackson. The key for statement 1, mentioned in Wikipedia, is that we can prove another relation, $kck = (kc)^3 k$. The obvious relations $c^2 = 1$ and $k^2 = k$ mean that we only need to look at alternating sequences of $c$ and $k$; that other relation means we can put a bound on the sequence length.

When I tried to access it this morning, it did not work. It seemed like the link was broken. Thanks - I will have a look.

Cool. The Proof section in the Wikipedia page is a little sketchy but it has the essentials too.

It seems like the proof is a lot easier than I thought. For some reason, I couldn't see why 15-sets would be impossible by this construction.
